# RoR: Rails query with connection.select_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to ruby on rails.

I tried a simple query and it works if I used @books = Book.find_by_sql(sql).  In the rails doc, it says I could also use connection.select_all like below.

```
def index
  sql = 'SELECT title FROM books'
  # @books = Book.find_by_sql(sql)
  @books = Book.connection.select_all(sql).to_a
end
```

However, I am getting this error in the browser related to hash.

> undefined method `title' for {"title"=>"Harry Potter II"}:Hash

This is what I have in the erb view:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= book.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
```

The query seems to be correct but something is still missing.  Appreciate if you could provide some hint.

Comment: `select_all` is used when you have a complex query and you want to get the results as an array of hashes instead of model instances. This is usually used when you're doing something like fetching aggregates or other queries that don't quite fit the ORM.  Its not really relevant here. Just use `@books = Book.all` which will run `SELECT * FROM books;` and give you model instances.

Comment: The comments in the duplicate clearly address this issue. Additionally if you want to use `ActiveRecord`esque methods then I would highly recommend conforming to the the standard rais ORM methodology. You are literally swimming against rapids to avoid using a bridge.